# Debugger always Break when invoke GetFileAsync in windows 8 store apps (metro style)

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

This problem confuse me several days, when the code run to

```
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(udFileName);
```

The app was always jump to

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

The Exception e is：

```
{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
Exception   {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   
System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
Message "System.NullReferenceException.......
```

Following is the function I invoked:

```
public async void RestoreUserDefaults()
    {
        string udFileName = "userdefaults.udef";
        bool bExist = true;
        {
            try
            {
                await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(udFileName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                bExist = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I had add the file type to the package.appxmanifest.

anyone can help me, so many thanks.....

Comment: It might not found a file for your udFileName, have you verified or tried to debug that what it returned is not null?